# Inline-blocks overlapped by flexbox in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

I have strange behavior of inline blocks in nested flexbox.
This happens in Chrome.

I use green block for spacing, nested `.row` need to show/hide all it's( content, if remove `display:flex`(or `.row`) from it -- `.spacer` not work.

Can anyone help?

[image: overlapped blocks]

```css
body {
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 50%;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.spacer {
  flex: 0 0 15px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #AEA;
}

.flex {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <body>
    <div class="row">
      <span>label</span>
      <span class="spacer">|</span>
      <div class="row">
        <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
        <span>date</span>
        <span class="spacer"></span>
        <span>date2</span>
      </div>
      <span class="flex"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-arrow-down"></span>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you want to achieve

Comment: I would like to have some `spacer` class, which can be used in `row` and `column` (by this I mean `flex-direction`)